# como pegar os horarios iniciais e finais e guardar em duas variaveis com javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

como pegar os horarios iniciais e finais e guardar em duas variaveis com javascript?

```
var hora1 =  '9h - 22h'
   var hora2 = '12h - 21h'

    var1 = 9
    var2 = 22
    var3 = 12
    var4 = 21
```

utilizando substring não consegui pois eles valores variam dinamicamente..

Comment: Daywison, dê atenção às suas perguntas. Olhando o seu histórico, você possui muitas perguntas não-resolvidas com várias respostas, e vc continua fazendo perguntas sem resolver as anteriores. Isso não é nada bom. Valorize os usuários que gastam tempo respondendo as suas perguntas. Escolha uma resposta e marque ✔️. Ou se nenhuma resposta resolveu o problema, questione quem respondeu para achar a solução. Abs!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var hora1 = '9h - 22h'.split('-'); //uso o 'split' para isolar cada valor

var h1 = hora1[0].replace(/h\s|h|\s/g, ''); //uso 'replace' com uma 
var h2 = hora1[1].replace(/h\s|h|\s/g, ''); //expressão regular para remover espaços e a letra 'h'
```

Answer (score 1):

Pode fazer desta forma com `while` verificando se as variáveis `hora` existem e criando as variáveis `var` separando os valores com `.split`:

```js
var hora1 = '9h - 22h';
var hora2 = '12h - 21h';

var hora = var_ = 1;

while(window['hora'+hora]){ // enquanto existir variáveis iniciando com "hora" + um número sequencial começando do 1
   
   var quebra = window['hora'+hora].split(" - "); // converto em array com dois índices
   
   window['var'+var_] = parseInt(quebra[0]); // primeiro valor pegando apenas o número
   window['var'+(var_+1)] = parseInt(quebra[1]); // segundo valor pegando apenas o número
   hora++; // incremento em +1
   var_ += 2; // incremento em +2
}

console.log(var1, var2, var3, var4);
```

> Lembrado que para usar `window[]`, as variáveis devem ter escopo global.

Se forem apenas essas duas variáveis (`hora1` e `hora2`), pode fazer assim:

```js
var hora1 = '9h - 22h'
 ,  hora2 = '12h - 21h'

 ,  quebra = hora1.split(" - ")
 ,  var1 = parseInt(quebra[0])
 ,  var2 = parseInt(quebra[1])

 ,  quebra = hora2.split(" - ")
 ,  var3 = parseInt(quebra[0])
 ,  var4 = parseInt(quebra[1]);

console.log(var1, var2, var3, var4);
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o  [String.prototype.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

```
var hora1 = '9h - 22h'
var hora2 = '12h - 21h'

var hora1array = hora1.split('-')    
var hora2array = hora2.split('-')

var1 = hora1array[0]
var2 = hora1array[1]
var3 = hora2array[0] 
var4 = hora2array[1]
```

Comment: Faltou só um parseInt(hora1array[0]). Essa função vai comer tudo que não é número, ou seja, o "h" e os espaços em branco que ficaram no split